# Is there a way to configure the memory resources for Spark using Pyspark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working on an ETL job with an SageMaker notebook that uses spark 2.4.0.
After joining a couple of tables I keep getting the following errors:

**Update--**
I was able to set up tis configuration:

```
 pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '12g'),   
                            ('spark.executor.cores', '10'), 
                            ('spark.cores.max', '8'),
                            ('spark.driver.memory','8g'),
                            ("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", '11'),
                            ("spark.num.Executors", '15'),
                            ("spark.driver.cores", '10'),
                            ("spark.executor.instances", '94'),
                            ("spark.default.parallelism", '17860'),
                            ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'),          
                            ("spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval", "10min")])
```

I have a very large instance for this to work; however, even with this I'm still getting memory errors. Now similar stack trace as the ones listed below but for: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o8027.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 38 in stage 68.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 38.0 in stage 68.0 (TID 2900, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1887)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2108)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2057)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2046)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3384)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5928.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 30 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:932)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:930)
       at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:930)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2126)
       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2039)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$6.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1949)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1948)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:575)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3384)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2545)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3364)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
       at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've used this Memory configuration for Spark that is demonstrated within EMRKS in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/) , I was able to set it up on my SageMaker Notebook, but it doesn't seem to pick it up.

is there a way to configure the Memory resources that Spark is using while performing the computations in the back end?

Comment: Which memory configuration exactly ?

Comment: @surya I edited the original post with the configuration I'm using up to now that seems to be partially working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Spark version 2.4.0 is not supported on Amazon SageMaker notebooks as of today. There is an open ticket regarding this issue on [Github](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-spark/issues/120)